# SQL query to hide the result of a single cell based on the value of another cell

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to come up with a query where given a table such as below, displays the list of games but hides the answer column for the rows where inProgress = 0.

[image: Table to query]

The only way I can think of is doing a simple query such as `SELECT * FROM game WHERE inProgress = 0;` is there any other function of SQL that lets me only hide or set the value of the answer column to the desired value where inProgress = 0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`case`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp). It's like an `if/else` for selecting columns.

```
select
  gameId,
  case
  when inProgress = 0 then
    null
  else
    answer
  end as answer,
  inProgress
from game
```

This will show all rows in `game` but if `inProgress = 0` it will not show the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MySql case statement.  You won't be able to necessarily hide the column, but you could put a value such as N/A or -1 in it to display what you are trying to get across.

```
SELECT gameId, inProgress, CASE when inProgress = 0 then -1 ELSE answer AS answer FROM game;
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar but more compact form of a *case expression*, you could use an *inline if*

```
select gameId, if(inProgress = 1, null, answer) Answer, InProgress
from game;
```

Comment: Note that [`if`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if) is not standard SQL, it is a MySQL specific function.